# Is hypochondria always about oneself?

Tags: meaning

I read the definition of *hypochondria*, but it does not say: is it correct to use this word, for instance, about parents who worry too much about their kid(s) being sick?

Comment: So you read a definition and decided to post a question based on it but didn't quote what you actually read!! Please quote it.

Comment: @Mohit Well it said that hypochondria was psychological (I can't find the exact sentence I read) and what was not clear was whether it could be about someone else than oneself and if not what would be the name for "hypochondria by proxy".

Comment: @Mohit Here's where I found a definition: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hypochondria

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hypochondria does indeed refer to the sufferer himself.

Worrying about other people's health should be called *hypochondria by proxy* (by extension from Munchausen by proxy) but I can't find a reliable reference for that. The best one is [a blog](http://littlemiao.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/the-final-result/) which implies that a vet has diagnosed it in a pet's owner.

Comment: I'm not so sure *Munchausen by proxy* wouldn't actually cover it. Sufferers *usually* actually induce the disease (or symptoms thereof) in the proxy, but I imagine they'd be quite happy to take advantage of any *real* disease the proxy just happened to have. And naturally, they'd exaggerate the disease just the way a hypochondriac would.

Comment: Lots of references I found separated it from Munchausen by proxy; for example, convincing oneself that a child's teenage acne is smallpox or some similar affliction. I'm sure there are over-protective parents and pet owners who wouldn't dream of *inducing* an illness -- hypochondria by proxy is almost the direct antithesis.

Comment: I don't know - the motivation is definitely to get the attention of  the medical professionals, rather than to actually *cause harm*. And they usually induce *symptoms*, not the disease itself. But to be honest, in the case of parents worrying about their not-actually-sick children, I think I'd just say *hypochondria* is the best available word anyway. Firstly, I don't think the popular use matches that of the medical profession, and secondly I'm not sure you can say the parent is meaningfully distinct from their child in such a context.

Answer (score 2):

There does appear to be a defined Hypochondria by proxy. This medical journal article even discusses two cases in 1999:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14685518